# Meaning of the "don't spring on the inner-spring this spring or there will be an offspring next spring"

Tags: meaning, proverbs, tongue-twisters

Today we encountered this tongue twister:

> Don't spring on the inner-spring this spring or there will be an offspring next spring

Is there any meaning of it? Or it's just a tongue twister without any meaning at all?

Comment: Sex tends to lead to pregnancy.  And sex tends to occur on inner-spring mattresses (among other places).

Comment: @HotLicks The only thing that is likely to confuse a native speaker about this is, IMO, the use of "inner spring" to mean *mattress*. Of course anyone reading this would understood what was meant by that word from context, but so far as I know no one uses "inner spring" standalone to mean *mattress*.

Comment: The "pun" doesn't really work anyway, because pregnancy lasts 9 months. That's 3 out of 4 seasons, so the offspring should arrive in ***winter***, not next spring.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Depends on how long it takes the spring to be sprung.

Comment: @Hot Licks: ...and whether [the grass is riz.](http://www.pbase.com/image/27088094)

Comment: "Don't jump on the mattress this spring or there will be a child next year."

Comment: @Hellion - It's not jumping on the mattress that leads to this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, guys. So I got that this tongue twister definitely not for the public audience :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers perhaps "don't spring on the inner-spring this spring or there will be an offspring before next spring" would be more appropriate

Comment: If the successful springing occurs on June 20, 2017, the offspring could arrive on March 22, 2018.  That's spring to spring, and 275 days, well within the normal gestation period.

Comment: If the offspring *arrives* next winter there will still (barring tragedy) "be an offspring next spring". Once they spring up, offspring tend to stick around for at least eighteen years, which is why you have to be careful not to spring them on yourself until you're ready.

Answer (score 2):

**inner-springs and sexual reference**

*Cosmo Kama Sutra The Sex Deck: 99 Sex Positions That’ll Blow Your Mind*

page 344  [google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=p2lNAQAAIAAJ&q=inner-springs%20noise%20and%20sex&dq=inner-springs%20noise%20and%20sex&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiik7v6z7PdAhVJslMKHZT1BPcQ6AEILzAB)

> ... relentless, scoring hit after hit, until your coccyx has intimate
>   knowledge of all 498 **inner springs**, If the anguish becomes unbearable
>   you only recourse is to fake a resounding orgasm.

The most likely sense is to sex, and that it can lead to ... pregnancy!

Answer (score 2):

"Inner-spring" refers to the American term [inner spring mattress](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/inner-spring-mattress). The other words are self-explanatory.